# Gamebanana accessing api

Tags: jquery, api

I want to access the [gamebanana api](http://gamebanana.com/wikis?page=direct_api_access) using jquery. My code looks like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.gamebanana.com/api?request=Member.1382.["user_title"]';
$.get(url, function(data) { console.log(data);
});
```

Accessing the url directly shows up a message about it being malformed.
Could the problem be with the quotes in the url or the braces?
Can someone give me an example on how to do it correctly?

Comment: What a miserable API design. Anyway, works just fine for me, you just need to use correct URL encoding: http://gamebanana.com/api?request=Member.1382.[%22user_title%22] However, you can't make cross-domain ajax calls unless the API supports JSONP or CORS.

Comment: Can you show me how to add url encoding?

Comment: Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the query param value, or pass the query param separately to `$.get()`, as in `$.get('http://www.gamebanana.com/api', { request: 'Member.1382.["user_title"]' }, function ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I ([RazerKat](http://gamebanana.com/members/143274)) wrote this wrapper in JavaScript. It works nicely but sometimes you may need additional stuff to make it work. Especially in GameBanana however this is a good start. It's also cross-browser compatible which makes it work in both Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. In this case GameBanana seems to be using GET requests to obtain the information from the server-side, so you just need to change POST to GET and remove the send variables and put the removed variables into the open request instead to make it fetch the data correctly. Also note that it can only run fine on their site specifically, you need to adjust the code to achieve desired effect.

```
    var DataObject;function AJAX_JSON_Request(p,d,u){var Request;if(window.XMLHttpRequest){Request=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{Request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    Request.onreadystatechange=function(){if(Request.readyState==4&&Request.status==200){DataObject=JSON.parse(Request.responseText),DataObject.XML=Request,DataObject.JSON=Request.responseText;}}
    Request.open("POST",u,true);
    Request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    Request.send(p+"="+d);}
```